# Entering nested url directly into browser in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have setup my `@RouteConfig` so that I have a `/login` route.

When I enter `www.url.com/login` directly in the browser, it doesn't go to the login page. It stays on the root path page.

Programatically I can tell the app to go to that page though through `routerLink` links. How can I get it to work so that when entering `www.url.com/login` it will go to the login page?

my `@RouteConfig`

```
@RouteConfig([                                                                   
  {path: '/',        name: 'Index', component: IndexComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/login',   name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},                  
  {path:'/register', name: 'Register', component: RegisterComponent}             
])
```

Comment: can you show ur @RouteConfig ?

Comment: @ciptohadi79 ok updated with RouteConfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the base url is `<base href="/">`

I can reproduce your problem if the base url for index html is like in the plnkr.co did to suit the url of the running demo (ex:http://run.plnkr.co/boByZFO8RKLNLKGx/), ie:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

If I change it to `<base href="/">`, the problem disappeared. Hope the problem solved

Comment: @Mlennie: if this solved your problem, you can mark this as the answer by clicking  the checkmark, so that it can help others